# Tone.JS - Additive synth

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, synthesizer, tone.js

I am trying to create a simple additive synthesizer using `Tone.JS` and the `WebAudioAPI`.

So far I have set up a simple synth which works fine and I am able to play whatever note I want.

I can also freely change parameters ecc...

Here is the code:

```
// synth declaration using Tone.JS

var synth = new Tone.Synth({
  oscillator: {
    type: 'fmsquare',
    modulationType: 'sawtooth',
    modulationIndex: 3,
    harmonicity: 2.4
  },
  envelope: {
    attack: 0.001,
    decay: 0.1,
    sustain: 5,
    release: 0.1
  }
}).toMaster()

//Possible added oscillator
 var synthB = new Tone.Synth({
   //Sample Data.......
 }).toMaster()

// Selection of piano keyboard from my HTML file

notes = document.querySelectorAll(".hex");

// Play note function

notes.forEach(function(note) {
    note.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){
    x =  event.target.title;
    synth.triggerAttackRelease(x, "8n");
    //synthB.triggerAttackRelease(x, "8n");

    });
});
```

I tried to add another `Tone.Synth` but I can not figure how to "*parallelize*" the process.

Looking at the [documentation](https://tonejs.github.io/) I found how to create a **polyphonic synth**, but it allows to add multiple instances of the same synth in order to play more than one note.

What I'd like to do is to play the same note with **DIFFERENT** synths (each one with its waveform) obtaining an additive synth.

I tried to simply create a `SynthB` and then call `synthB.triggerAttackRelease()`,it works fine, but it doesn't seem "parallel" to me.

Are there any better approaches?

Comment: I've never used Tone, but I have made a vst in c++.  My guess is that what you'd want to do is get the two synths to share the envelope.  Otherwise, two different synths playing the same note is exactly what additive synth layers (or parallel) are.

Comment: That's not the real problem, if i'd like to make them share the envelope, i could simply assign a variable A (for example the Attack), put it inside the envelope of the oscillator and change it.

My problem was more "hardware", so far i'm calling 2 .triggerAttackRelease() one after the other. Does this cause any problems when i start stacking multiple Synth?

Comment: So far both the synth play together because (i think) my browser is so fast at execute those instructions that they seem parallel. But if i start messing around with chain of filters after the oscillator ecc..., would i encounter any lag problems this way?

Comment: You'll very likely run into lag eventually, I worked with the WebAudioAPI a while ago... it has limitations.  But in terms of what you're doing, so far it is correct.  If you made unique filters, fx, etc for every synth layer it might become a problem, but as is, two parallel synths in any program are really just two separate synths playing the same note.  It is the definition of layering.

That being said, depending on the synths, it might be possible to get some performance gains by getting a single synth to generate the sound.  Look into wavetables.